# Get different alert on page load,refresh and close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I want to show alerts for the following events:

1. Page onLoad
2. Page Refresh
3. Before Close

Comment: I am sure there are dupes on this, but there is NO way to know what it is doing.

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Comment: kindly accept an answer if they solve your problem. Otherwise be sure to comment and explain what you are searching for with more detail. :)

Comment: Currently I develop disable multi login user. As per client requirement when tab close or browser close that time user logout automatically. for that I have find out javascript event using I call ajax and clear database session id

Comment: That would be `onunload` > function logout(), Sir. :P

Comment: @RaisingAgent onunload event trigger when page refresh also. That's issue when using onunload and onbeforeunload event

Answer (score 2):

Use `alert` for load , and `return` statement for unload and refresh

below the used code .

```js
// 1-Page Load
window.onload = function() {
  alert("Page loaded");
  
  //disable unload message when clicking on links (<a>)
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length ; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    })
  }
}

// 2-Page Refresh or  3-Before Close 
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Page unloaded !";
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Comment: I have a feeling the OP already knows about these events and wants to know how to determine the difference between refreshing the page and closing it, which is impossible.

Comment: It is possible actually^, but the tab will still be closed

Answer (score 1):

**Add** this to your `<head>` tag, you can pick between `onbeforeunload` and `onunload`, which ever you prefer. Although `onunload` also gets triggered, when you close the tab / browser.
 The `window.alert` triggers, when the page is loaded.
*This is **it**:*

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.alert("alert!");
  
  window.onunload = function (){
      alert("onunload alert");
  };
  window.onbeforeunload = function (){
      alert("onbeforeunload alert");
  };
</script>
```

Comment: I have a feeling the OP already knows about these events and wants to know how to determine the difference between refreshing the page and closing it, which is impossible.

Comment: Improbable I'd say

Comment: I would agree with that assesment!

Comment: Your answer still cannot distinguish those events, though. Browsers do this for good reasons!